# Inline unix command as filename

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following bash script test.sh (with execution permissions):

```
#!/bin/sh
CAT_BIN="cat"
"$CAT_BIN"  <(tail -n +2 test.sh)
```

It gives me that error when I run it:

```
$ ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 4: `"$CAT_BIN"  <(tail -n +2 test.sh)'
```

However, when I source the following commands it executes alright.

```
$ CAT_BIN="cat"
$ "$CAT_BIN"  <(tail -n +2 test.sh)
```

How can this work in a script? (Use `<(tail -n +2 test.sh)` inline as a filename argument)

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` can do it. `#!/bin/sh` cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<(tail -n +2 test.sh)` construct is a bash feature, so you need to run your script in the `bash` shell,

Replace your top line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(Or the proper path to the bash executable if it is not `/bin/bash` on your system)

Note, even if `/bin/sh` is e.g. a symlink to bash, it will start bash in [posix compatibility mode](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour#posix_run_mode) when you run it as `/bin/sh` , and many bash specific features will not be available)